# how to use regex on tags inside tags?

Tags: c#, regex

im currently writting on a little project here that uses regex to parse a template, now the big problem is that we also got a "tag" for includes here which makes it kinda difficult.

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"##############TEMPLATEENGINE(^#)##############(.*?)##############TEMPLATEENGINE(\1)##############", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

works fine on templates like

> ########TEMPLATEENGINE$$startswith$$account:firstname$$Firstn##############
>
> blah
>
> ########TEMPLATEENGINE$$startswith$$account:firstname$$Firstn
>   
>   ########TEMPLATEENGINEaccount:firstname############## Attribute missing: firstname! ##############TEMPLATEENGINEaccount:firstname

but as soon as i have a template like

> ########TEMPLATEENGINE$$startswith$$account:firstname$$Firstn##############
>
> blah
>
> ########TEMPLATEENGINEaccount:firstname############## Attribute missing: firstname! ##############TEMPLATEENGINEaccount:firstname
>   
>   ########TEMPLATEENGINE$$startswith$$account:firstname$$Firstn##############
>
> blahg

it just finds the inner template, although i think that \1 should make sure that start and end should be equal....

Comment: Can you please provide details bit more clear?

Comment: What does "tags inside tags" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I had a go at getting this pattern to work:

```
########TEMPLATEENGINE([^#]+)##############(((?!########TEMPLATEENGINE(?!\1)).)*)########TEMPLATEENGINE\1##############
```

But no luck so far and I need to move on - I've posted it anyway in case it helps, as I think the technique is sound. I will delete it later (or fix it, if I can!) if nobody makes use of it, so please don't vote it down - I'm not claiming it's a complete solution!

Note that you'd need to iterate the match expression, capturing the inner tags first.

Also note that the end tag for ########TEMPLATEENGINEaccount:firstname############## seems to be in a different format for the example (missing it's # suffix) - is that a problem?